# Difference between maven/ant/gradle

Tags: maven, ant, gradle

I think the title tell everything. I'm just wondering what is the min difference between those three solutions. Are they all equivalents or they don't even do the same thing. I've try to find some documentation but I'm not able to get a clear difference between Ant Maven and gradle.

Comment: Maven and gradle are basically the same. Ant is more like script language like Makefiles.

Comment: yeah, my bad sorry for that

Comment: for me very helpful this manual http://goo.gl/vaB9he
compare Gradle with others build systems

Comment: @Absurd-Mind What do you mean ~"**basically the same**?  Gradle is an embedded DSL inside a Turing-complete, dynamically typed language.  Maven is just XML.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky the concepts are similar. Sure one is configured through XML, the other is "programmed". Ant on the other hand is just a writing down of tasks.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Does Maven support classes, inheritance and injection?

Comment: seriously guys, go somewhere else to argue about that. this poat is more than 2 years old.